# get objects list of session in template of Django

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I need a total ticket number. "tickets" is a list. tickets list have 3 items.

```
Shopping Bag ({{  request.sessions.tickets|length }})
```

output;

```
Shopping Bag (3)
```

but result;

```
Shopping Bag (0)
```

Comment: `request.sessions` should be `request.session`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{  request.session.tickets|length }}
```

should do it. `session` instead of `sessions`

Answer (score 0):

Even i have experienced the same issue. One alternative is you can pass { "tickets":request.sessions['tickets'] } in render and try {{ tickets|length }} in template.